# joining two arrays, with a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to combine two arrays, `arr1` and `arr2`, into a larger array. While I know there are the `apply()` and `push()` methods, I have to use a loop to do it instead (the longer way I guess).

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr2 = [5, 6, 7];

function appendArray (arr1, arr2) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length + 1; ++i) {
        arr1.push();
        return arr1;
    }
}

var result = appendArray(arr1, arr2);
alert(result);
appendArray(arr1, arr2);
```

Obviously, it isn't working at the moment and I am struggling to figure out the syntax. I understand the logic but that isn't doing me much at the moment.

Comment: but your `.push()` call has no reference to `arr2`. It isn't even trying to append anything.

Comment: why do you need a slow loop when a fast native call will do the job?

Comment: here's a fiddle for all your SO friends: http://jsfiddle.net/Y28pp/ - also, use net.uk.sweet's answer, it's better.

Comment: If you want to add the elements of `arr2` to `arr1`, you have to iterate over `arr2`, not `arr1`, and actually pass the element to `.push()`. It actually looks more like the logic is the problem, not syntax.

Comment: Please explain why you can't use `arr1 = arr1.concat(arr2)` or `arr1.push.apply(arr1, arr2)`.  It appears that you are reinventing a wheel that doesn't need reinventing.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
var result = arr1.concat(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is you function to join two array ..first argument will be combine with second and return

```
function appendArray (arr1, arr2){
 for(var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
 arr1.push(arr2[i]);
 }
return arr1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this way

```
var j = arr1.length;
for(var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    arr1[j] = arr2[i];
    j++;
}
return arr1;
```